# I would like to get data from the internet, but i have an error at the connection

Tags: ios, objective-c

Below is code:

`[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url usedEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding`

Xcode gives error : `no visible @interface for "NSString" declares the selevtor "initWithContentsOfURL:url usedEncoding`

So what is wrong here?

Here the full code:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://google.com"];
NSStringEncoding encoding;
NSString *my_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url usedEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

if ([my_string length] == 0) {
   UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Internet Connection"
                                                       message:@"A connection to the Internet is required to access this page."
                                                      delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];

   [alertView show];
}
```

`

Comment: Are you just trying to see if your app has Internet connectivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a parameter in here :

```
NSString *my_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url usedEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

It should be :

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSStringEncoding enc;
NSString *my_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url usedEncoding:&enc error:&error];
```

As it's stated in [NSString Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/initWithContentsOfURL%3ausedEncoding%3aerror%3a) :

```
- (instancetype)initWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url usedEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError **)error
```

Be sure to trust the warnings in Xcode. In this case, I think, it should tell you that it can't find the method signature in `NSString` class before you compile the code.
And also always check with Apple's documents if you aren't sure about method names or signatures. It'd help you coding faster :D

EDIT: I fixed the code as @David suggested, thank!

---

EDIT : Added full code with some more explanation

If I understand it correctly, **you only want to convert `NSData` to `NSString` that you already knew it was in UTF8 encoding.**

If that's the case, you used a wrong method. **The method you used is for converting `NSData` to `NSString` and figuring out what encoding it is in.** That why you have to supply it with a pointer of NSStringEncoding.

Back to your case, this is what your full code would look like :

```
NSError *error = nil; // I added this 
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://google.com"];
NSString *my_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url  
                                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding // and changed this
                                                        error:&error]; // and added this

if ([my_string length] == 0) {
   UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Internet Connection"
                                                       message:@"A connection to the Internet is required to access this page."
                                                      delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];

   [alertView show];
}
```

But if i was wrong, this might be your full code :

```
NSError *error = nil; // I added this
NSStringEncoding enc; // also this
NSString *my_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url 
                                                 usedEncoding:&enc // changed this
                                                        error:&error]; // and added this

if ([my_string length] == 0) {
   UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Internet Connection"
                                                       message:@"A connection to the Internet is required to access this page."
                                                      delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];

   [alertView show];
}
```

Comment: You'll still get errors.  The `usedEncoding:` parameter is passed by reference, so you'll need to pass in NULL or an NSStringEncoding pointer.

Comment: oh! thank you to point it out. actually I haven't ever use this method before lol.

Comment: so can somebody leave the the complete code right here

Comment: YEY, thank you very much... the first one works